# How to get partial expression from symbolic expression containing specific variable MAPLE?

Tags: symbolic-math, maple

I have a symbolic expressions as below

```
y1 = (1/a)-(b/a^2)+x*a*b-x/b
y2 = a*b+a*x+b*sqrt(x)
```

now I need to get the partial expressions which have specific term. Like

```
xFunction(y1, x) # should return x*a*b-x/b
xFunction(y2,x)  # should return a*x+b*sqrt(x)
```

any suggestions or idea are very healpful
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
restart;

y1 := (1/a)-(b/a^2)+x*a*b-x/b:
y2 := a*b+a*x+b*sqrt(x):

K := (ee,x) -> `if`(ee::`+`,select(depends,ee,x),ee):

K( y1, x );

                     x
             x a b - -
                     b

K( y2, x );

                     (1/2)
            a x + b x     

#
# Leave alone an expression which is not a sum of terms.
#
K( sin(x+4)*x^3, x );

                         3
             sin(x + 4) x 

#
# Don't select subterms in which `x` is a just dummy name.
#
K( x^3 + sin(x) + Int(sqrt(x), x=a..b), x );

               3         
              x  + sin(x)
```

[edited]

```
y1 := (1/a)-(b/a^2)+x*a*b-x/b;

                      1   b            x
                y1 := - - -- + x a b - -
                      a    2           b
                          a             

op(3,y1);

                         x a b

depends(op(3,y1), x);

                          true
```

The `select` command maps its first argument over
all the operands of its second argument.

```
select( s->depends(s,x), y1 );

                               x
                       x a b - -
                               b
```

A more terse syntax, where `select` maps its first
argument `depends` over the operands of its second
argument, and passes its third argument as additional
options (to the selector).

```
select( depends, y1, x );

                               x
                       x a b - -
                               b
```

Now create a procedure to do it. Use a conditional
test, so that it returns the first argument itself
whenever that is not a sum of terms.

```
K1 := proc(ee, x)
  if type(ee,`+`) then
    select( depends, ee, x );
  else
    # leave it alone
    ee;
  end if;
end proc:

K1( y1, x);

                               x
                       x a b - -
                               b
```

Using a more terse syntax for that type-check.

```
K2 := proc(ee, x)
  if ee::`+` then
    select( depends, ee, x );
  else
    # leave it alone
    ee;
  end if;
end proc:

K2( y1, x);

                               x
                       x a b - -
                               b
```

Using a more terse syntax for that if..then..end if.
This is the so-called operator form of `if`. The word
`if` is within name-quotes, to distinguish it from the
language keyword within an if...then...end if .

```
K3 := proc(ee, x)
  `if`( ee::`+` , select( depends, ee, x ), x );
end proc:

K3( y1, x);

                               x
                       x a b - -
                               b
```

Since the body of the procedure K3 has only a single statement then
we can make it more terse, using the so-called operator
form.

```
K4 := (ee, x) -> `if`( ee::`+` , select( depends, ee, x ), x ):

K4( y1, x);

                               x
                       x a b - -
                               b
```

Comment: Great. It is so compact code and working perfectly. I am very glad  and thankful :). I am new to maple and doing my basics. I really can't understand how that Line of code is doing exactly. If possible kindly provide me related link for some material for the above code

Comment: I added a breakdown of the terse code in the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
listOfTerms = op(expression);  # y1 or y2
numberOfSubExpressions=nops(expression); # for y1 or y2

requiredTerm = 0;

for i 1 to numberOfSubExpressions do 
    if has(listOfTerms [i], x) then # x is our required term
       requiredTerm := requiredTerm +listOfTerms [i] 
    end if 
end do
```

Above code does my requirement. But, if are there any bugs for special expressions please let me know. Because op function behaves differently when we have functions like(sin,cos Log ..etc)