# make sub-expressions based on addition(+) operator MAPLE

Tags: symbolic-math, maple

Arbitrary expression be

```
test := a*b*c+x+a*y+c*z;

output := SomeCommand(test, `+`);
output
      [a*b*c,x,a*y,c*z];
```

Is there any command to do it as a expression.

I did this by converting it into string and using StringSplit command. converting each element from list to expression  and in for loop.

```
test := convert(test, string)
with(StringTools):
output:=StringSplit(test, "+")
     ["a*b*c", "a*y", "c*z", "x"]
InertForm:-Parse(output[1])

value(output[1])
    a*b*c
```

but, My interest is to get this done as a expression. is there any possibility??

Answer (score 2):

You're question has input but no output. You should observe that the *expression* that you've assigned to **test** may have its addends stored in a different order from which they are typed in the *input*.

It is possible to pick off the addends of a sum, and put them in a list. The very simple code for this is below.

The order in which the addends appear in the list match the order in which they are stored internally.

```
restart;

f := proc(expr)
   if type(expr, `+`) then
      [op(expr)];
   else
      expr;
   end if;
end proc:

test := a*b*c+x+a*y+c*z;

             test := a b c + a y + c z + x

f( test );
                  [a b c, a y, c z, x]
```

Are you the same fellow who's asked all these (somewhat related) questions? Or taking the same course? [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368691/how-to-get-partial-expression-from-symbolic-expression-containing-specific-varia) [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382409/how-to-construct-sub-expressions-with-only-two-variables-and-one-arithmatic-oper) [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420940/extract-complete-expression-and-functions-name-from-the-standard-function-mapl/52431878#52431878) [Q4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519052/convert-a-set-to-expression-maple-change-prefix-to-in-fix-expression)
If so then could you just tell use what you're really trying to accomplish?